Angular: use POST instead of GET to retrieve third party API data (Error 400 url too long)
I am developing a little project to understand HTTP requests. For this, I am using a third party API that I call to.
Data Police API
My project has a library of all neighbourhood boundaries in lat and long coordinates. I use these boundary coordinates as a query to API for street level crimes (as mentioned in the document linked below).
Street Level Crimes
Example request:
getComments(): Observable<APIData[]> { return this.http.get<APIData[]> ('https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=52.268,0.543:52.794,0.238:52.130,0.478&date=2017-01'); }
There are some neighbourhoods that have exceedingly complex boundary coordinates, leading to extremely long URL requests due to query parameters. The document above mentions:
'The API will return a 400 status code in response to a GET request longer than 4094 characters. For submitting particularly complex poly parameters, consider using POST instead.'
How do you use the POST method to return API data to my front end webapp?

you'd use return this.http.post... but the API has to support that.

yes but this.http.post requires another arugment for the body to send  to the API. As in for that it would be: this.http.post(url, bodyargument). so how would I be using POST to retrieve the data, instead of sending data?

I imagine you should use some like
getData()
{
  const data={poly:....;
            date:'2024-06'
           }
  return this.httpClient.post("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime",data)
}

but really the API doc is not very clear
NOTE: Yes, post can be use to retrieve data, typical, a login ussually is a API POST call
